# Custom Tab Bar Segue App Crash Deallocated Instance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom Segue for my app.  The app has a Tab Bar on the left side with five buttons on it.  The main view TDViewController has a UIViewController (UIViewController * currentViewController) and a UIView (View * placeholder). I use the below code for my custom segue.

```
@implementation TDCustomTabBarSegue
- (void) perform {

    TDViewController *vc = (TDViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dstVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    for(UIView *view in vc.placeholder.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    vc.currentViewController = dstVC;
    [vc.placeholder addSubview:dstVC.view];
}
```

All is well until I attempt to click on a button in my current placeholder view.  I get the error [MyViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7562e70

I figure my my view controller is not being retained, but don't know how to fix my problem.

**Edit -- Additional Info**

```
TDTViewController.m
...
- (IBAction)modeButtonClicked:(id)sender; //hooked up to storyboard

TDTViewController.m
...
- (IBAction)modeButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    //hooked up to storyboard
}
```

This issue is not exclusive to my UIButton.  Interacting with any control in my placeholder View will crash the app with the same deallocated instance error.

The profiler gives me a zombie on TDTViewController. Event Type = Malloc, RefCt = 1, Responsible Caller = -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]

Comment: There is not enough info in the post to know what the problem might be. You are likely forgetting to retain a ref on your object with a @property declaration, but there is no way to know based on the small code snip you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the method for the button which button has to perform

something like

```
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSubImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```